# Is there a way to use custom counting query in Spring JPA with Specification parameter

Tags: hibernate, jpa

one of the tables we have for events is a bit large (>900Gb). One of the use cases is to get the last 10 rows with pagination and some filter. Currently, it uses "Specification" instead of a custom query and it works fine, but counting total rows is pretty slow.

```
Page<EventData> findAll(Specification<EventData> criteria, Pageable pageable);
```

in some cases, when there is a broad filter, I could return an approximation of the total count, but how can I do that without annotating with custom @Query (there I could write my own counting query)?